# React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement> causing TS errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I tried to extend a React component with React.HTMLProps and not explicitly define onClick in its attribute list, and instead have it be "caught" and applied by the `...{rest}` attribute in the code. However, ESLint complains when I try to pass onClick when using the component.

I have a React component that looks something like this:

```
const someComponent = ({
   someAttributes,
   ...rest
}: SomeComponentProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>): JSX.Element => (
   <li>
      <a
         ...everything else
         {...rest}
      >
         ...children stuff
      </a>
   </li>
```

Now, from another repo, where I have this component imported, I try to pass "onClick" as an attribute to someComponent -- and while it works as intended, TS will complain. This is how the code looks like:

```
<someComponent
    ...everything else
    onClick={() => setShowSomething(true)}
>
Open something
</someComponent>
```

And the TS error I get is (indicated by a red line underneath 'onClick'):

> TS2322: Type '{ children: string; href: string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkListItemProps'.   Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkListItemProps'.

Is the reason for this error simply because TS linting does not harbor the capacity to understand that onClick is actually assignable to the component, or is it correct, at least to some extent, in that it should be done differently for readability? Is there a way around this?

(For practical reasons, the component cannot be a button-element)

Comment: have you tried? React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that TypeScript's type checking is not able to infer that `onClick` gets passed through via the `{...rest}` props.

There's a couple ways you can fix this:

1. Explicitly allow the `onClick` prop in `SomeComponentProps`:

```
interface SomeComponentProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {
  // other props  
}

const someComponent = ({onClick, ...rest}: SomeComponentProps) => {
  // ...
}
```

2. Assert that rest contains any extra props:

```
const someComponent = ({
  someAttributes, 
  ...rest 
}: SomeComponentProps & {[x: string]: any}) => {
  // ...
}
```

3. Use the `JSX.IntrinsicElements` utility type:

```
import { JSX } from 'react'

const someComponent = (props: JSX.IntrinsicElements['a']) => {
  // ...
}
```

The last method is nice because you get completions for all allowed props on the `a` element.

Overall the issue is TypeScript cannot safely allow extra props through `{...rest}`, so we need to make it explicitly aware.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Specifically it was number one I tested. Interestingly, the onClick doesn't have to be explicitly passed when the interface extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>. Thanks!